# Call Meteor method inside Apollo Mutation

Tags: reactjs, meteor, apollo, react-apollo

I've defined some `Meteor methods` on the server that I need to be executed only on the server (`Meteor.isServer`). Now I want to call these methods on `Apollo resolvers` using `Meteor.call`, but this does not seem to work.

```
Meteor.methods({ 
  'post.add': function addpost(data) {
    new SimpleSchema({
      data: { 
        type: Object
      },
      'data.title': { type: String },
      'data.body': { type: String },
      'data.tag': { type: String },
    }).validate(data);
    return Post.insert(data);
  }
});

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    doSomething(){ 
      return Meteor.call('post.add', data);
    }
  }
}
```

But calling the method on the client (after removing Meteor.isServer) work fine.
Another issue is using resolvers Mutation function inside another Mutation function:

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    addData(){ ... }

    doSomething(){ return this.addData(); }
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot `return Meteor.call(...)`. put the `Post.insert(data)` into the mutation or define a function and call the function instead of the Meteor.method. (btw, you can attach schemas to your collections so you don't have to `validate` every time)

Comment: @dabe that was just an example. The method does far more than just Post.insert. I've also defined a set of function as a class on the server, and import them to be used inside the Mutation, but even that does not work.

Comment: That actually worked out. I forgot to define my functions as `static` is the file where they were imported from.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a JS [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) where I define some `static functions/methods` (to be able to call the methods without **instantiating** it's `class`) and used them in my `resolvers`.

```
// some file .../Utils
class Utils{
  static someMethod({arg1, arg2, ...}){
    ...do something
  }
}
export default Utils;

// In my resolvers
import Utils from '.../Utils'
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    const a = ...;
    const b = ...;
    const c = Utils.someMethod({a, b, ...}); 
  }
}
```